# how to scale data in a range of (-1, 1) exclusive, instead of inclusive

Tags: python-3.x, normalization, preprocessor, minmax

I am using python preprocessing to scale my data. I used MinMaxScaler with parameters of feature_range=(-1, 1). But this returns data in a range of [-1,1]. I need data in a range of (-1,1). How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure how those ranges are different. Are saying you need a tuple — (-1, 1) instead of a list — [-1, 1]? You can use the `tuple(list)` to convert.

Comment: @MarkM the notation is mathematical set inclusion `[]` and exclusion `()`. OP is saying that he's getting values in the range `(-1,1)` inclusive, but wants `(-1,1)` exclusive

Comment: Gotcha thanks @4o2

Comment: Why do you need that? While @4o2's approach will fulfil the requirement, you easily may end up with some questionable calculations afterwards (like _Now |x|<1 for sure, let's divide things with (1-|x|)_ still might not be a great idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an odd question, because in general scaling is inclusive - by definition, scaling to `(lower_bound, upper_bound)` means the smallest thing in the data set gets mapped to `lower_bound` and the largest to `upper_bound`, so it's sort of contradictory to say you want an exclusive range, because then the "maximum" of the range is not mapped to by anything in the data.

This is why there is no functionality to do so - scaling to a range is always inclusive. I would consider carefully why you need an exclusive scaling - i.e. whether you really do.

That said, here are some ideas, **which are both mathematically dubious** (they will introduce some error):

1.) `feature_range = (-1 + eps, 1 - eps)`: where `eps = .000000000000001` or a suitably small number. Narrowing the acceptable range by an arbitrarily small number **approximates** an exclusive range as the number `eps` approaches 0.

2.)

```
for entry in data:
    if entry is 1:
        entry = entry - eps
    else if entry is -1:
        entry = entry + eps
```

This is even more mathematically dubious because it will artificially "push in" the ends of your distribution, but it will leave the mapping unchanged for every value greater than `(-1 + eps)` and less than `(1 - eps)`.